# What's the difference between the 2 groups of instructions given below regarding the non-use of the prefixes 66/F2/F3?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, instruction-set, instruction-encoding

Section 3.1.1.1 on Chapter 3 of Volume 2 of Intel's documents says the following regarding **NP**:

> **NP** — Indicates the use of 66/F2/F3 prefixes (beyond those already part of the instructions opcode) are **not** allowed with the instruction.
> Such use will either cause an invalid-opcode exception (#UD) or result
> in the encoding for a different instruction.

After looking at some of the instructions in the manual I found that:

1. These are few examples of instructions containing the **NP** in its encodings: ADDPS, ANDPS, ANDNPS, BNDLDX, BNDSTX. There are many others having the same **NP** in its encodings.
2. These are examples of instructions that **don't** have the prefixes 66/F2/F3 in its encodings: ADD, AAD, AAM, AAS and ADC. *But they don't show the **NP** in its encodings*.

What's the difference between the instructions in those two groups in relation to the non-use of the prefixes 66/F2/F3? In other words how does the presence of NP in group 1 differentiates these instructions from the ones in group 2?

Comment: For SSE instructions, none/66/F2/F3 indicates the operand type (ps/pd/ss/sd for float, b/w/d/q for integer).  So adding one of these prefixes will change the operand type.  That's some of those in your group (1).  As for group (2), these traditionally ignored F2/F3 prefixes (but honoured 66 prefixes, using them to change between word and dword operation), so they may still do (but it's not guaranteed to work).

Comment: Additionally, there are instructions where none/66/F2/F3 is just used to encode two additional opcode bits and using the wrong prefix causes #UD or a different instruction.  For example, compare `JMPE` (`0f b8`) and `POPCNT` (`f3 0f b8 /r`).

Comment: The manual may not be exhaustive with its use of `NP` on every instruction encoding where it's applicable.  Or as fuz said, `66 AAM` will still decode as AAM on current CPUs; that prefix+opcode combo hasn't been repurposed for anything else yet, and won't #UD.

Comment: That's clear now. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @PeterCordes: are you talking about in particular modes? ```66 AAM``` may not have been repurposed, but the byte sequence ```66 D4 0A``` does ```#UD``` in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @sj95126: I'm talking about modes where `aam` is encodeable in the first place, i.e. non-64-bit modes.  I tested on my Skylake in a 32-bit executable with `db 0x66` / `aam`, and yeah forgot to be more specific in my phrasing about "won't #UD".  The way I was thinking about it, in 64-bit mode `66 d4 0a` isn't `66 aam`, it's nothing, as per the "Invalid" entry in that column of [the manual entry](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/aam)

Comment: Sorry, for integer SSE operations, only `66` is a meaningful prefix, switching from MMX to SSE.  The prefixes `f2` and `f3` are only used for a few integer SIMD instructions like `pushflw` and `pshufhw` and that in a fairly unsystematic manner.

Comment: @sj95126 From [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69274448/whats-the-difference-between-the-2-groups-of-instructions-given-below-regarding#comment122443729_69274448), how does one verify that `66 D4 0A` does `#UD` in 64-bit mode? That is, how do I insert the byte `66` in the instruction `AAM`?

Comment: @Belloc: It's tricky when it's an invalid sequence, an assembler probably won't accept it as instruction nmemonics. I have an OS kernel I've been writing, so I modified a section of assembly and added ```.byte``` directives (AT&T syntax) to explicitly include those three bytes and ran it. It triggered the invalid opcode exception handler.

Comment: @PeterCordes From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69274448/whats-the-difference-between-the-2-groups-of-instructions-given-below-regarding#comment122443760_69274448) above, it seems like you were able to insert the prefix `0x66` into an `AAM` instruction with `db 0x66 / aam` to conclude that it doesn't  `#UD`. If I'm  understanding you correctly, will something similar to this work in MASM? See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69274448/whats-the-difference-between-the-2-groups-of-instructions-given-below-regarding#comment122487437_69274448) above to @sj95126.

Comment: @Belloc: I'm pretty sure MASM allows `db 66h` on a line by itself anywhere in a code section.  You don't "insert `66` into `aam`", you just tell the assembler to emit a `66` byte, then separately (on the next line) tell it to emit an `aam` instruction.  But in 64-bit code `aam` isn't a valid mnemonic, so you'd use `db 66h, D4h, 0Ah` to emit those three bytes into the output at the current position.  (Unlike NASM, MASM only allows trailing-h for hex literals, not C-style `0x..`)

Comment: @PeterCordes Superb. I was able to include the `db 66h` in the code section before the `aam` instruction and the code didn't #UD, in Visual Studio. Thanks for the great tip.